# Windows 10 clipboard sync not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, sync, clipboard, windows-10-v20h2

I have two windows 10 laptops both on the latest version of Widows 10 Pro (20H2). I've logged in using the same Microsoft account on both. Have another account on one pc but I added the common Microsoft account as a family member to it and I use the common account now. My problem is the clipboard sync works sometimes but not always. I have enabled it in settings and checked the option "automatically sync copied text".

In clipboard history Win+V of the pc from where I copied text, it says synced at so and time, but the text isn't appearing in the other pc. I assume both the devices send the text and text has reached MS servers but both of them don't retrieve the synced text from MS; they don't show copied text from eachother.

I also tried enabling the group policy settings for clipboard settings on both devices, restarted both several times but still the text I copy on one doesn't immediately appear on the other. At times after a restart text from other appears but that isn't what I need. I would like to have the clipboard synced always between these two devices. How to make this work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sync feature is connected to the Microsoft Account.  So are both accounts on each device connected to the exact same Microsoft Account?  You indicated that is the case but you also indicated your using parental control (Family Account).  These devices are both connected to the internet at all times, I presume?

Comment: Yes both are connected to internet and I've added the 1st PC's ms account on second pc as a family member and I use that to login to my 2nd pc but I also have another account on the 2nd pc. In clipboard history Win+V it says synced at so time, but the text isn't appearing in the other pc.

Comment: "but the text isn't appearing in the other pc." - which account is that PC logged into?

Comment: Both PCs are logged in using the same Microsoft account when I'm trying to sync clipboard.